# How to get the information of a column in Python which has a dictionary in every row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe obtained from an API. My result dataframe has a dictionary in the columns and I would like to obtain the information on them.
This is a sample of my dataframe:

[image: My dataframe]

How to get the values in the yellow columns? and how to save this dataframe in CSV?

Thanks in advance for your help!
This is the code to obtain the dataframe from an API:

## Get active disruptions, filtered by road ids

```
r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Road/A2%2C%20A406%2C%20A1%2C%20A12%2C%20A13/Disruption?app_id=XXXXXXXXXX&app_key=XXXXXXXXX')
r = r.text
df7 = pd.read_json(r)
df7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
columns = ['geography','geometry']


for col in columns:
    d = df7.loc[0,col]
    for key in d.keys():
        df7[key+'_'+col] = df7[col].apply(lambda x: x[key] if x is not np.nan else np.nan)
```

try this for all the columns by replacing geography with the col name

Comment: Thank you! And this result can I save in a dataframe? and after in a csv?

Comment: Yes, of course. Does it work for all the columns needed?

Comment: It worked but only for the first row. It did not get all values of the column, only the first one :(

Comment: Are dictionary key values consistent in a column?

Comment: Yes, this is what I got: {'type': 'Point',
 'coordinates': [-0.048519, 51.507114],
 'crs': {'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'EPSG:4326'}}}

Comment: I made an edit. It works for geography and geometry

Comment: When I tried with geometry I got this error: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable. How to update my dataframe with these new values? Thanks a lot

Comment: Okay, I see that there are nan values so changed the lambda fun

Comment: Now I have results for geometry but I dont have for geography :(

Comment: I am able to get. Try again. You need to do the same thing for all columns

Comment: Do you change something in the code to get the values of geography?

Comment: No, I am running the same thing here. The columns will be towards the end. Try printing df.columns and you should get 'type_geography'

Comment: But I have a dictionary as result of your code not a dataframe. Could you please tell me how to save this result in a dataframe?

Comment: @ Parijat Bhatt could you please help me? Yesterday I run the code and was correct, but now I got this error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: I ran it and it still works for me.  Are you trying the above code? Can you try once more?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will work regardless of dictionaries with differing keys or columns that contain a mix of dictionaries and other types.

Note: I have removed the API key for the request, you will need to add it back in.

```
from functools import partial
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq

api_key = ""
url = "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Road/A2%2C%20A406%2C%20A1%2C%20A12%2C%20A13/Disruption?app_id= XXXXXX&app_key={}".format(api_key)
r = rq.get(url)
r = r.text
df7 = pd.read_json(r)

output_path = "disruptions.csv"


def keys_if_dict(element):
    if isinstance(element, dict):
        return list(element.keys())
    return list()


def value_for_key(element, key):
    if isinstance(element, dict) and key in element:
        return element[key]
    return None


def handle_dicts_in_column(df, column_name):
    column = df[column_name]
    if any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict), column)):
        # this column has dictionaries in it

        column_dict_keys = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(column.transform(keys_if_dict)))

        for dict_key in column_dict_keys:
            column_name_from_dict_key = "{}_{}".format(column_name, dict_key)
            while column_name_from_dict_key in df.columns:
                column_name_from_dict_key += "(dup)"

            df[column_name_from_dict_key] = column.transform(partial(value_for_key, key=dict_key))

            if any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict), df[column_name_from_dict_key])):
                handle_dicts_in_column(df, column_name_from_dict_key)


for column_name in df7.columns:
    handle_dicts_in_column(df7, column_name)

df7.to_csv(output_path)
```

Comment: I removed the URL because it contains your API key. This is probably not something you should share, and I didn't want to re-share it if that could be avoided.

In order to run this, you should add the URL to the copy of the code you run locally.

Answer (score 0):

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd  # version 0.25
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.read_json(r)
```

### `DataFrame.explode` to move each item in a list to a separate row:

- `recurringSchedules` is either `nan` or a `list` of `dicts`

#### Code:

```
df = df.explode('recurringSchedules')
```

### Replace `nan` in the rows of interest:

- `geography` and `recurringSchedules` each have rows where the value is `nan`

  - each `nan` will be replaced with an appropriate `dict`, where `value` is `np.NaN`, as shown in `geo_json` & `recur_sched_json`
- rows with data are `dict` type
- using json_normalize on `list` or `nan` throws `AttributeError`

#### Code:

```
geo_json = {"type": np.NaN, "coordinates": np.NaN, "crs": {"type": np.NaN, "properties": {"name": np.NaN}}}
recur_sched_json = {'$type': np.NaN, 'startTime': np.NaN, 'endTime': np.NaN}

def replace_nan(df_row: (dict, float), dict_nan: dict) -> dict:
    if type(df_row) != dict:
        return dict_nan
    else:
        return df_row

df.geometry = df.geometry.apply(lambda x: replace_nan(x, geo_json))
df.recurringSchedules = df.recurringSchedules.apply(lambda x: replace_nan(x, recur_sched_json))
```

### Reset the index:

- using `DataFrame.explode()` changed the number of rows in the `DataFrame` from 13 to 24

#### Code:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

### `json_normalize` the `dicts`:

- each `key` in `dict` will get its own column

#### Code:

```
df_dict = dict()
for x in df.keys():
    try:
        y = json_normalize(df[x])
        y.columns = [f'{x}.{col}' for col in y.columns]
        df_dict[x] = y
    except AttributeError:
        df_dict[x] = df[x]

df_new = pd.concat([df_dict[x] for x in df_dict.keys()], axis=1)
```

- each `json_normalized` column (e.g. `geography`, `geometry`, `recurringSchedules`) now has its own `DataFrame` in `df_dict` and can be accessed as follows
- `df_new` combines all columns into a single `DataFrame`

#### Code:

```
df_dict['geography']
```

[image]

### Save to csv:

#### Code:

```
df_new.to_csv('geo.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

### Notes:

- `geometry.coordinates` was not expanded because it consists of groups of nested `lists` with the following lengths:

  - `[28, 1, 96, 65, nan, 1, nan, 50, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, nan, 596, 596, 596, 52]`
  - Each number represents a nested `list` (e.g. one cell contains 596 nests `lists`)
- Similarly, `geography.coordinates` was not expanded, though, each row value is a single `list`
- Take all the **Code:** sections to transform and save the `json` file.