# How can I get the information from a dataframe containing dictionaries or lists in every column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this information and I can't get the values of the columns `serviceTypes` and `crowding`:

```
id  name    modeName    disruptions lineStatuses    serviceTypes    crowding
0   piccadilly  Piccadilly  tube    []  []  [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line...   {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowd...
1   victoria    Victoria    tube    []  []  [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line...   {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowd...
2   bakerloo    Bakerloo    tube    []  []  [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line...   {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowd...
3   central Central tube    []  []  [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line...   {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowd.
```

I tried this code:

```
def split(x, index):
    try:
        return x[index]
    except:
        return None
dflines['serviceTypes'] = dflines.serviceTypes.apply(lambda x:split(x,0))
dflines['crowding'] = dflines.crowding.apply(lambda x:split(x,1))

def values(x):
    try:
        return ';'.join('{}'.format(val) for  val in x.values())
    except:
        return None
m = dflines['serviceTypes'].apply(lambda x:values(x))
dflines1 = m.str.split(';', expand=True)
dflines1.columns = dflines['serviceTypes'][0].keys()
dflines2 = dflines1[['name']]
dflines2
```

But I got this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-8f4bb6ac731a> in <module>
     14 m = dflines['serviceTypes'].apply(lambda x:values(x))
     15 dflines1 = m.str.split(';', expand=True)
---> 16 dflines1.columns = dflines['serviceTypes'][0].keys()
     17 dflines2 = dflines1[['name']]
     18 dflines2

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `keys()` is for dictionary. However the value inside the column serviceType is a `string`. Hence it's failing. Simply remove `.keys()` to get the column values

Comment: It should be df['servicetypes'][0][0].keys()

Comment: @PirateX it does not work, I have this error: TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, '[' was passed.. any thoughts?

Comment: @ParijatBhatt, no it does not work in this code.. any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the source of your dataframe or the csv here

Comment: @Alexa Can you share the datatype of `serviceType` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the information of a column in Python which has a dictionary in every row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564880/how-to-get-the-information-of-a-column-in-python-which-has-a-dictionary-in-every)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull a pandas column into a list like so:

```
service_types = dflines['serviceTypes']
```

The first value is now the the first value in the list service_types.

```
first_value = service_types[0]
```

Pandas works differently than a dictionary. I think you might be trying to treat the data frame as a dictionary. Apologies if I misunderstood or oversimplified.

Edit:

Ok, it looks like service_types ( above) is a list of dictionaries. To write the column so that it only contains the type you need to index into the list and then index into the dictionary.

```
service_types = dflines['serviceTypes']
types_alone = []
for i in service_types:
    types_alone.append(i['$type'][0])
dflines['new_column'] = types_alone
```

Comment: She is trying to access the first value in the service type col and then access the keys of the first value in that list

Comment: @angrymantis, could you please show me how to get this values in a dataframe? because I need to get servicesTypes and crowding in a dataframe

Comment: Do you mean you want to rewrite the serviceTypes column so that it only contains the type?

Comment: @angrymantis I want to extract the values from the columns serviceTypes and crowding to get them and after join to the original dataframe and have the complete information

Comment: @Alexa I think I did that in the edit. Is it correct that there is only one value associated with the key '$type'?